# Sync row data based on unique ID in google sheets scripts

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I currently have a code that does something very similar to this, but im not sure the small change i need to make to have it work correctly. Right now, the code below compares two rows of unique IDs and if the IDs are the same, it copies the cell in the "Comments" column to the other sheet.

```
function setComments() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      compare1 = "", compare2 = "",

      outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"),
      sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"),

      range1 = outputSheet.getDataRange(),
      range2 = sourceSheet.getDataRange(),

      lastCol1 = range1.getNumColumns(),
      lastCol2 = range2.getNumColumns(),

      values1 = range1.getValues(),
      values2 = range2.getValues(),

      // get the range of the titles
      titleSection1 = outputSheet.getRange(1,1,1, lastCol1),
      titleSection2 = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,1, lastCol2),

      // get the values from the titles
      titles1 = titleSection1.getValues(),
      titles2 = titleSection2.getValues(),

      // get the column # for "ID" and "comment"
      idCol1 = titles1[0].indexOf("ID"),
      idCol2 = titles2[0].indexOf("ID"),
      commentsCol1 = titles1[0].indexOf("comment"),
      commentsCol2 = titles2[0].indexOf("comment");

  // get the IDs from range1
  for (i = 1; i < values1.length; i++) { 
    compare1 = values1[i][idCol1];

    // get the IDs from range2
    for (j = 1; j< values2.length; j++){
      compare2 = values2[j][idCol2];

      // if same ID, change the values array
      if (compare1 == compare2) {
        values1[i][commentsCol1] = values2[j][commentsCol2];
      }
    }
  }
  // set values based on the values array
  range1.setValues(values1);
}
```

Instead, if there is a change made to any cell on sheet 1, it will find the identical cell based on unique ID in the other sheet and sync the change. What change do i need to make to have this work?

For example, if I change what the office is in the row of ID 1 of sheet 1, it will make the identical change for ID 1 in sheet 2.
Here is an example sheet of what im working with:

```
Sheet 1:
ID   Comment   Number   Office    Clinician 
1    good       22345    Dallas  
2    bad        12345    Denton
3    good       95954    Lubbock
4    bad        20204    FT.W
5    bad        11111    Denton
6    good       02944    Preston
Sheet 2:
ID   Comment   Number   Office    Clinician 
1    good       22345    Dallas 
3    good       95954    Lubbock
5    bad        11111    Denton
```

Comment: Anyone have an update for this? Let me know if i need to provide some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one data set on Sheet 1, and a subset of that data set on Sheet1. The key field is the "ID". If there is a change to data on Sheet 1, and the ID relating to that change is found on Sheet 2, then you want to update the relevant dataset on Sheet 2.

The key aspects of this answer are:

- `onEdit(e)`: This is an [simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).
- `e.range`: "range" is an [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). By using the attribute 'e'; it is possible to recover a substantial amount of information about the changes. In addition, the event objects can be further used to obtain more information - such as (in this case) the Row, Column and Sheet Name.
- `filter(String).length`: Sometimes getting the last row of data is problematic. The answer gets all the data in Column A, and uses the Javascript "[array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)" method. In this case is simply counts the values as strings, andf the resulting value is equal to the Last Row of data.
- the "IF" statement evaluates for several attributes:

  - Is the edit on Sheet1?
  - Is the edit on a row between the header and last row?
  - Is the edit in a column that contains data?
  - the operator is "&&" which requires that each of the attributes must return true.
- `targetdata.map(function(e){return e[0];});`: the script gets ALL the data on Sheet2, but uses the Javascript [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate a subject of just the values in Column 1 (the ID column).
- `targetCol1.indexOf(sourceID);`: The script uses the Javascript "[array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)"; if the ID is found, it will return the index number of the row on Sheet2; if the value isn't found, it will return "-1".  The enables a logic statement to be written that will be executed only if the value is not "-1"
- `target.getRange(+result+1,1,1,sourceLC).setValues(sourcedatatocopy)`: the last lines of the script get the values in the edited row on Sheet 1, and then update the values on Sheet2. Note: it updates all the values for the matched ID - rather than identifying the changed field and updating only that field.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // setup spreadsheet and sheet names
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSN = "Sheet1";
  var source = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSN);
  var targetSN = "Sheet2";
  var target = ss.getSheetByName(targetSN);

  // get row, column and sheet of the edited sheet
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var editedsheet = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: editedsheet = "+editedsheet)

  // get the ID column from Sheet 1
  var SourceCol1Vals = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var SourceLR = SourceCol1Vals.filter(String).length;    
  // assign value to last column
  var sourceLC = 5;

  // test for sheet, row range and column range
  if (editedsheet == sourceSN && row >=2 && row <=SourceLR && col <=5){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: this is sheet 1 & the right row and the right Col")
    // get the data for this row
    var sourcedata = source.getRange(row,1,1,5).getValues();

    // get the data from target
    var targetdata = target.getDataRange().getValues();
    // get only the ID column
    var targetCol1 = targetdata.map(function(e){return e[0];});
    // get the sourse ID
    var sourceID = sourcedata[0][0];
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: source ID = "+sourceID)

    // search for source ID on the Target list
    var result = targetCol1.indexOf(sourceID);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: id was found at "+result);

    if (result !=-1){
      // if -1 then couldn't find the ID, otherwise it returns the index number where it finds the match
      // get the data for the Source ID
      var sourcedatatocopy = source.getRange(row,1,1,sourceLC).getValues();
      // update the darget for the sourceID data.
      target.getRange(+result+1,1,1,sourceLC).setValues(sourcedatatocopy)
    }

  } else{
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: not sheet 1 or  right row or right col");
  }

return;
}
```

Comment: This worked great! I appreciate the thoroughness of this script and explanations!